# MySQL database connection through PowerShell, old style password

Tags: mysql, powershell, passwords

I am attempting to connect to a MySQL server through powershell. However, my password doesn't seem to work because "Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords." I am using the MySQL ADO.NET driver to connect and everything has returned no error up to this point.

```
# Connection Variables 
$user = 'cantshowusernamehere' 
$pass = 'PretendRealPassword' 
$database = 'PretendDatabaseHere' 
$MySQLHost = 'something.something.ca' 

# Connect to MySQL Database 
$conn = Connect-MySQL $user $pass $MySQLHost $database
```

will return me

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Authentication with
>   old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords."

Anyone know how I can change to a new style password through PowerShell? Thanks, I have been searching for a couple hours now, and the only solutions out there are for people utilizing other programs such as PHP for their SQL work.

Comment: Where did you get the `Connect-MySQL` cmdlet, or is it a custom function?

Comment: http://www.blakepell.com/Blog/?p=615  It seems the .net connector requires you to reset the user password on the mysql server to use a newer hashing method for password storage.

Answer (score 1):

I had to down-grade the version of MySQL .NET Connector I was using (latest: 6.9.7, fell back to [6.5.7](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.5.html)).  I realize this goes against the common wisdom of "fix your database server", however it's internal and there are far too many resources using this to weigh the risk of setting `old_passwords=0` and resetting all of the (known) passwords to update their hashes (just to find out we've broke some buried tool somewhere)